# clojure maven configure

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2, clojure

i had very nice dev. env. - clojure, maven and jetty with hot deploy. now i moved to google appengine and i can not figure out how to configure maven achieve hot deploy

Answer (score 1):

There is a [google app engine plugin for maven](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/plugin-info.html) that supports deploy. Hot-deploy is not mentioned but this is where I'd start. Not sure if it works for clojure but I see not reason why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with `gae:run` that currently doesn't hot deploy changes (see [Issue 47](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=47&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Version%20Summary)). Maybe try the suggested workaround.